# Can't find Ip of raspberry Pi board

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi-os

I want to connect locally Raspberry Pi 4 model B via ethernet with GUI.
I go with this instructions: https://howchoo.com/pi/find-your-raspberry-pis-ip-address.
But command `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` don't return raspberry Pi board IP. Then I find this instructions: [Cannot connect to Pi Zero through SSH headless mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61538/cannot-connect-to-pi-zero-through-ssh-headless-mode?newreg=d53ec7a8b01247959c882d6df9e9badc). And I can't modify config.txt file. I tried this one : [How to edit config.txt](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71399/how-to-edit-config-txt). And command `sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot` return `mount: /boot: mount point not mounted or bad option.`.

When try to connect to Raspberry Pi via VNC Viewer, I connect board via ethernet, I have got `The connection was refused by the computer`. This is `vncviewer.log`:

```
<14> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: Localize: Locales en_US
<14> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CModuleHosted: Getting CloudConfig.pkg from built-in resource
<14> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CModuleHosted: Using business identifier 7ebb19da-7740-4238-8f0e-d5d8bc77f350
<14> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CModuleCtrlComms: Listening on /tmp/.vnc-1000/vncviewer.CtrlComms.26651
<14> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: GoogleAnalytics: X.509 Error: Certificate expired
<13> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.580Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CSession: Connecting to 192.168.1.249 (Chooser for Direct UDP/Direct TCP via proxy settings)
<11> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.616Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CSession: connection error: connect: Connection refused (111)
<13> 2022-07-25T12:55:25.616Z dmitriy vncviewer[22977]: Child: 26651: CConnection: close: [System-111] The connection was refused by the computer
```

The output of `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-25 16:13 MSK
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.0
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0059s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
Host is up (0.0064s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.085s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.52
Host is up (0.0020s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.98
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.145
Host is up (0.0035s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.147
Host is up (0.0030s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.152
Host is up (0.099s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.161
Host is up (0.0020s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.182
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.189
Host is up (0.22s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.198
Host is up (0.062s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.222
Host is up (0.077s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.224
Host is up (0.078s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.238
Host is up (0.52s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.240
Host is up (0.074s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.242
Host is up (0.14s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.243
Host is up (0.19s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.246
Host is up (0.11s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 13.57 seconds
```

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: How is the Pi connected to a network?  Show a diagram of the connections.

Comment: How is your Pi connected to your network - wired or wireless? Most routers or access points show ip addresses of connected devices.

Comment: wired connection

Comment: This question is vague. You have tagged with 2 totally different OS. What Pi? Why  do you care what the address is - you should be able to connect to hostname.local

Comment: I want connect locally Raspberry 4B  via ethernet with GUI.

Comment: The connection was refused by the computer means the server wasn't on on that time. You should check server on time or not.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall system on other micro-SD and it is gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than editing the config file is to enable SSH when you're getting the OS (Raspbian) itself. I realized this when using a Windows system and think it should be valid in your case too. The relevant portion from [that](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138374/how-do-i-setup-raspberry-pi-4-to-use-with-a-windows-laptop) answer is posted here:

> 1. Access the Raspberry Pi Imager for Windows (***Ubuntu in your case)*** from the official site. Do
>    not select the default 32-bit version, but the 64-bit version if you
>    are using a 64-bit laptop. I was unable to connect with the 32-bit OS
>    on 3 different laptops, two running Win 11 and 1 running Linux (Mint).
> 2. In the advanced options (gear icon), do the following: (i) Set
>    host-name to something that you easily remember (I used 'pi').
>    (ii)Enable password authentication; choose your username and password.
>    (iii) Configure the Wireless LAN, country, Time Zone and the first two
>    'persistent settings'. (If you don't have your SSID at hand, check
>    network and internet connections through the WiFi icon in the taskbar.
>    Right click the active connection to get details, including SSID).
>    Save this configuration.